# Struggling to communicate between processes with signals

Tags: c, linux, terminal, signals, pipe

I'm trying to create a game in C under linux terminal.

I need to create a tetris game that consists of two c files,
One C file create execute file (a.out) and the other create (draw.out).
The first program create a child process and execute the other.

I need to send signals to the other program, but I found it difficult.

The source code is:

the first file-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <signal.h>

char getch();

int main()
{
    int fd[2],pid;
    char *args[] = { "./draw.out", NULL },tav;
    pipe(fd);
    pid=fork();
    if(pid==0)
    {
        execve("draw.out", args, NULL);

    }
    else
    {

        while(true)
            kill(0,SIGUSR2);
    }

    return 1;
    //getchar();

}

char getch() {
        char buf = 0;
        struct termios old = {0};
        if (tcgetattr(0, &old) < 0)
                perror("tcsetattr()");
        old.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
        old.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
        old.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
        old.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
        if (tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &old) < 0)
                perror("tcsetattr ICANON");
        if (read(0, &buf, 1) < 0)
                perror ("read()");
        old.c_lflag |= ICANON;
        old.c_lflag |= ECHO;
        if (tcsetattr(0, TCSADRAIN, &old) < 0)
                perror ("tcsetattr ~ICANON");
        return (buf);
}
```

the second file-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <signal.h>


typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
}Point;

typedef struct
{
    Point dots[3];
}Tool;

void drawBoard(int array[][20]);
void initBoard(int array[][20]);
Tool retrieveTool();
bool changeLocation(int array[][20],Tool* tool);
void my_handler(int signum);

int main()
{
    bool nextTool=true;
    Tool temp=retrieveTool();
    int gameBoard[20][20];
    signal(SIGUSR2, my_handler);
    initBoard(gameBoard);
    changeLocation(gameBoard,&temp);
    drawBoard(gameBoard);
    while(true)
    {
        signal(SIGUSR2, my_handler);
        sleep(1);
        system("clear");
        if(!changeLocation(gameBoard,&temp))
            temp=retrieveTool();
        drawBoard(gameBoard);
    }
    return 1;
    //getchar();

}

void initBoard(int array[][20])
{
    bool isLast=false;
    int i=0,j=0;
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        if(i==19)
            isLast=true;
        for(j=0;j<20;j++)
        {
            if((j==0)||(j==19)||(isLast))
                array[i][j]=1;
            else
                array[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
}

void drawBoard(int symbols[][20])
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<20;j++)
            if(symbols[i][j]==1)
                printf("*");
            else
                if(symbols[i][j]==2)
                    printf("-");
                else
                    printf(" ");
        printf("\n");
    }
}

Tool retrieveTool()
{
    Tool temp;
    int startX=0,startY=8,i=0;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        temp.dots[i].x=startX;
        temp.dots[i].y=startY;
        startY++;
    }
    return temp;
}

bool changeLocation(int array[][20],Tool* tool)
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        if(array[tool->dots[i].x+1][tool->dots[i].y]!=0)
            return false;
    }
    i=0;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        array[tool->dots[i].x][tool->dots[i].y]=0;
        if((tool->dots[i].x+1)==19)
            tool->dots[i].x=-1;
        tool->dots[i].x++;
        array[tool->dots[i].x][tool->dots[i].y]=2;
    }
    return true;
}

void my_handler(int signum)
{
    if (signum == SIGUSR2)
    {
        printf("Received SIGUSR1!\n");
    }
}
```

The draw.out is the output file of the second file.

i created the signal handeler in the second file,
But the program still don't recieve the signal, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you keep reinstalling the signal handler on every pass through the loop?

Answer (score 1):

This fragment:

```
while(true) kill(0,SIGUSR2);
```

has no sense. The kill should be used with the process id of the reveiver of SIGUSR2 (the child process in this case, identified by pid). Also note that an infinite loop sending signals to the child process is not what you want.

In the child process, you have an error in the print statement at signal handler:

```
printf("Received SIGUSR1!\n");
```

should be

```
printf("Received SIGUSR2!\n");
```

Depending on the OS version, you have to reinstall the signal handler once it gets called

Note: you are synchronizing processes, not threads

Comment: well i tryied to send the pid variable to the kill but it still don't call "my_handler" function. This function supposed to be a tetris game, and the second program running in a loop, so i want the second program check for signal every time. that why i send the signal from program number 1 in a loop, how should i do it else?

Comment: And the printf has no meaning, i made it just to check if the signal work

Comment: printf from a signal handler is generally regarded as unreliable. It _should_ work, but the set of functions which can be called reliably from handlers is rather limited.

Comment: Ok it's work now! thank you, but one more question. why when i execute the second program from the first , every time the second program need to print something, It's write "TERM enviroment variable not set" what is that?

Comment: and how can i send chars trought pipe to "my_handler" from the first program?

Comment: make another question. Use execlp instead of execve

Comment: Ok i will make another question, but for the execlp, how should i use it? the same as execve? just switch to execlp or it get another arguments?